# Excel VBA Index/Match within IF function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to setup a VBA code that loops through each cell in column M and returns the value of Column L if the cell contains a number, and goes through an index/match function if Column L doesn't contain a number.  Then if the index/match doesn't find what it's looking for, it goes through another vlookup.  I'm having trouble with the syntax of the third part of this (the vlookup at the end). I'm not sure if it should be another Else statement or an if statement or an ISerror or something different entirely.  Right now I have it set up as the second if/else. I'm also wondering if I will have problems due to the fact that the index/match function has text as the input and should return a number. Any suggestions/advice on this is much appreciated. Below is what I have so far.

```
Sub Ranking_2()

Dim cell As Range, rng As Range
Set rng = Range("L2:L120")

For Each cell In rng
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(cell.Value) Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = cell.Value
    Else: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("K:K"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cell.Offset(0, 1) & cell.Offset(0, 5), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A:A") & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H:H"), 0))
        If:cell.Offset(0,1).Value= WorksheetFunction.IsError(
        Else: cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cell.Offset(0, -11), ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:D136"), 3, 0)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Ashley, is there a reason you are using VBA to insert worksheet functions into the cells instead of just using VBA to do what the functions are doing? This looks like a lot of work to accomplish something simple.. Simple being commit to functions in your worksheet, or VBA in a module. Just curious as to why you're going about it this way.

Comment: Hey Tyeler, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. I'm new to VBA so this was the only way I found on how to do achieve what I'm trying to do, it's quite possible there is an easier way. I'm not doing this as formulas in excel because it's part of a larger code that will be executed many times and it should be faster to do in VBA. If there is a simpler way to write this in VBA could you expand on how to do so?

Comment: That was all I needed to know. Let me see if I can't put some code together to get you on the right track. :D

Comment: I'm a little lost on your first `Else`. Lets say `L5` is `Apple`. You then concatenate the strings (not range) at `M5` and `Q5`, try to find a match in... This is where I get lost. What do you want that line to do? I guess what I'd like to know is: Find _WHAT_, look for it _WHERE_, return _WHAT_? With INDEX as you had before, if `L5` is `Apple`, are you trying to see if it will return `Apple` or not?

Comment: Actually.. Do you want that line to search for whatever's in that cell, and if it is there then return it's value, if it's not then go on to a third lookup? What's the point in doing two separate lookups?

Comment: I know there is some wisdom to using as much built-in functionality as you can; however the index/match and vlookup functions in Excel are not efficient -- especially not compared to a Dictionary structure.  Since you are using VBA anyway, consider using Dictionaries.  I realize you range is extremely small (100 or so cells), but bear in mind that index/match and vlookup scale very poorly.

Comment: @hambone I figured a `.Find()` would easily take care of the second statement, and the third. No setup required. It seems like she just wants to find IF there is a match, not return a range or address or anything. Then again, referencing a single dictionary with all the possible searches...

Comment: Thank you both for the help! Sorry it's taken me a little while to respond. To your 1st question Tyeler, if the value is not a number I want to use the data in both columns H (I should have put -5) and M on sheet 3 to return the value in column K on sheet 1. Essentially, I need two pieces of information to return the proper value from sheet 1. Essentially, I need it to return a value that can only be found by looking for two pieces of information.

Comment: The other tricky part of this is that I will have multiple ranges that I run this on, and the size of the ranges will change. Right now I'm just trying to make the formula work for the first range as it is now, but later this range will have more rows and then I will also need to run the program on the range below the first (which will have a different starting cell based on how big the first range is). I think I can do this through dynamic naming, as the ranges will all have the same unique string in column A. Just another caveat that may or may not affect how this code should be written.

Comment: @Ashley, did you try the code in my answer?

Comment: Hey @user3598756 sorry I haven't been able to try it yet, hoping to do it tonight or tomorrow and get back to you. Thanks so much for sending that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to adopt these changes to your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Ranking_2()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim lookUp1Sht As Worksheet
    Dim lookUp2Rng As Range
    Dim val1 As Variant

    Set lookUp1Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LookUp1Sht") '<--| set the worksheet you're making the first lookup
    Set lookUp2Rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LookUp2Sht").Range("A1:C136") '<--| since you're this range returning column "C" value it suffices limiting it to column "C"

    For Each cell In Range("L2:L120").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| limit looping through wanted range not blank cells only
        With cell '<--| reference current cell
            Select Case True
                Case IsNumeric(.Value) '<--| if current cell value can be evaluated as "number"... 
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = CDbl(.Value)
                Case Not IsError(LookUp1(lookUp1Sht, .Offset(0, 1).Value, .Offset(0, 5).Value, val1)) '<-- if "first" lookup doesn't return an "error"...
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = val1 '<--| then write the 3rd argument passed from LookUp1() function
                Case Else '<-- if all preceeding "cases" failed...
                    .Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(.Offset(0, -11), lookUp2Rng, 3, 0) '<-- write "second" lookup return value
            End Select
        End With
    Next
End Sub

Function LookUp1(sht As Worksheet, val1 As Variant, val2 As Variant, val As Variant) As Variant
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String

    With sht '<--| reference passed worksheet
        Set f = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=val1, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) '<-- look for first passed value in its column "A"
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if found...
            firstAddress = f.Address '<--| store found cell address to stop subsequent FindNext() loop upon wrapping back to it
            Do '<--| loop
                If f.Offset(, 7).Value = val2 Then '<--| if corresponding value in column "H" matches val2...
                    val = .Cells(f.row, "K") '<-- set 3rd argument to value in column "K" corresponding to the "double" match
                    Exit Function '<--| exit function
                End If
                Set f = .Range("A:A").FindNext(f) '<-- go on looking for val1 in column "A"
            Loop While f.Address <> firstAddress '<-- stop looping upon wrapping back on first cell found
        End If
    End With
    LookUp1 = CVErr(xlErrValue) '<-- if no "double" match occurred then return "#VALUE!" error
End Function
```

please note that:

- change "LookUp1Sht" and "LookUp2Sht" to your actual worksheets names
- `Match` and `LookUp` `Application` functions handle possible errors without halting the macro and simply returning the error value

  This I only used in `.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(.Offset(0, -11)...`, so that if the "last chance lookup" ever returned an error you would have it written in your `.Offset(0,1)` cell
- use [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157(v=office.15).aspx) method to return a filtered group of the range you call it on: for instance using `xlCellTypeConstants` as its `Type` parameter you'd get back not empty cell only
- use [`IsNumeric()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264560.aspx) function instead of [`WorksheetFunction.IsNumber()`[(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840818(v=office.15).aspx) since the former will recognize string "5" as a number, while the latter would not

Comment: IT WORKED. THANK YOU SO MUCH!! The only thing now is to name each range. If you have any insight there please let me know!

Comment: You sre welcome. As per this site rules:1) a nee issue must be asked with a new post 2) since I fullfiled your question please marl my answer as sccepted. Thank you.